Stripping paint off cupboards without damaging gloss underneath
I have cupboards that were painted but the person who painted them didn’t sand them at all, so the paint is peeling.
We started peeling the paint and like the look of the natural wood underneath.
Is there a way to take the paint off with like a paint thinner or stripper that won’t affect the natural wood underneath that has a gloss to it?

Any nice finish on the wood will probably look yucky after and will need refinishing anyway.  Most paint strippers will not hurt the wood.

Depending how bad the paint job is, you could try a plastic scraper (e.g. old credit card or similar) and/or roll on packing tape (press it solidly onto the paint and let sit for a while) and then peel it off, and see how much paint comes off that way, before resorting to chemical strippers.
Any gloss on the natural wood is another layer of finish (it's just clear/transparent finish, not pigmented paint.) Unless it's much more resistant to the stripper, it will also be removed when stripping the paint, and you'd typically expect that stripping would be followed by some sanding and a fresh coat of clear finish. But it may be a more resistant clear coat, depending on the process used at the factory that made them.
Moving to steel or carbide paint scrapers is another option if you reach the point of the paint being stubborn enough (at least in spots) that you'll need to sand and re-coat the wood after removing paint, if you'd prefer to avoid the chemical stripper approach.
